# How to access proprietary XHR methods using JQuery 1.5 AJAX functions (jqxhr object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqxhr

I am developing  for a proprietary browser (samsung tv) that provides a special method xhr.destroy() wich has to be called after every AJAX completed. My question is, is there any way to access this method (or any browser proprietary method ) using jquery AJAX functions? Since they don't return the real XHR object, should jqxhr.destroy() work?

According to the documentation:
"jqXHR is a superset of the browser's native XMLHttpRequest object".

I understand that all methods and properties of the original XHR are inherited but that doesn't seem to be the case. I don't have the real environment yet but I'm trying to access jqxhr.withCredentials in the returned jqxhr object as a test (this property should exist in Firefox 3.6) but it is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery 1.5.1 , there is a setting in $.ajax function: [xhrFields](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
So you can set any params of real XHR like this:

```
$.ajax{
xhrFields:{
    param:value
}
}
```

Comment: xhrFields can be used to SET values in XHR objet. But what i need is to access XHR methods in the response. Something like jqxhr.destroy() in the 'complete' callback